# "Record" doesn't create keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes

I'm just a beginner with animations in Blender, but how my teacher showed me is that you can click on the "Record" button, place your object, turn "record" off, move the object, hit record again to create keyframes, turn off Record", etc.

I've done it a few times successfully, but the new animation I'm working on doesn't create keyframes:

Object in position 1

[image]

I turn "Record" on and move the object:

[image]

But no keyframes were created!

[image]

Comment: you are in edit mode, that recorder works in object mode, since keyframes era created for objects. if you need to change the "shape" ogf the object, you need to learn to use shapekeys (and you can animate them too)

Comment: The record button is a toggle for automatic keyframe insertion, it is not meant to be clicked on/off to insert keyframes. To insert keyframe in object-mode use the `I` hotkey.

Comment: the record button may work also in that way, but just does not work in the edit mode...

Comment: @m.ardito you gave a good answer, make it so that I can accept it! Also, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **Record** Button keyframes automatically every change in the Viewport.
But that recorder works only in object mode, so not in Edit Mode, since keyframes are created for objects. Also it works for all properties in Blender wich already have one keyframe inserted. If you change them then they are automatically keyfamed too. If you need to change the "shape" of the object, you need to learn to use shapekeys (and you can animate them too).

However, you can also keyframe and animate the Vertices (because with your method you don't move the object, only the vertices) directly in the Edit Mode with the **AnimAll** Add-on. But this will only playback properly in Object Mode.

Comment: I didn't know about animall, @Leon95 edited the answer in a much better shape and also added about it... I'll have to check it!